# gdb claims realloc() or free() corrupt memory while valgrind claims non-null terminated array run off...which is it?

Tags: c, heap-memory, realloc, strcat, corrupt

#### Background

I am working on a program where a thread, which is spun off a main thread, parses email logs and organizes each entry by the QID, an ID unique to each message.

#### Problem

The program was working find until I reorganized it so that instead of loading the entire log file first into memory, I begin parsing each line as I read in the log file.  The program will SIGABRT in the code snippet shown below (slightly simplified but demonstrates the same problem).

#### Debug Results

gdb will claim that it's either (depending on the run) realloc/free invalid size or realloc/free corrupt memory, while valgrind consistently claims a non-null terminated array causing a run off and corrupting the heap (which I believe is more likely the case but cannot find the problem).  (Let me know if you would like me to share the raw output of valgrind or gdb).

```
void *parseMessageAndMatch(void *params) {
    // get params passed in from parent thread
    parse_params *rp = (parse_params *)params;

    // len0: length of log dump for current QID
    // len1: length of log dump after current buffer is appended
    int len0, len1;
    // tmp char pointer for log dump
    char *tmp;

    // 1. increase/allocate memory for log dump and append line buffer
    // get length of current log dump (0 if NULL)
    // dump is of type char* and contains the log lines pertaining to a certain QID
    len0 = (!msgs.msgs[rp->index].dump) ? 0 : strlen(msgs.msgs[rp->index].dump);
    // get length of log dump after current line buffer is appended
    // rp->len contains the strlen of the line buffer
    len1 = len0 + rp->len + 1;

    // allocate space for tmp log dump
    // lock becaus msgs is a global variable and there is more than one thread
    pthread_mutex_lock(rp->mutex);
    if ((tmp = realloc(msgs.msgs[rp->index].dump, sizeof(*tmp)*len1)) == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot allocate memory for log dump.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    // update pointer
    msgs.msgs[rp->index].dump = tmp;
    // set tmp to null
    tmp = NULL;
    // if original buffer was empty, zero it out for safety
    if (len0 == 0)
        bzero(msgs.msgs[rp->index].dump, sizeof(char)*len1);

    // rp->line is malloc'ed then bzero'ed and strcpy'ed to contain the log line read from file
    strcat(msgs.msgs[rp->index].dump, rp->line);
    msgs.msgs[rp->index].dump[len1-1] = '\0'; // add null terminator
    pthread_mutex_unlock(rp->mutex);

    // more parsing code is here but was commented out during my debug process
    // so I have omitted it from this code snippet

    // free line buffer
    free(rp->line);
    // set to null to prevent double free
    rp->line = NULL;
    // free params
    free(rp);
    // prevent double free
    rp = NULL;
}
```

#### EDIT

made correction in answer below.

Comment: gdb says `realloc` resp. `free` found an invalid size or a corrupt heap. That will be due to writing outside array bounds as valgrind says.

Comment: What is `msgs`? Rather than posting more, I'd prefer if you posted *less*, and instead post the relevant bits of the code. Narrow it down until you have  a minimal example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Right, thanks!  So next time around when I realloc the heap is corrupt, and hence the SIGABRT. Now I just need to find what's causing the overflow...any suggestions on debugging techniques or tools for this one?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Thanks for the suggestion - I knew I posted too much but wasn't sure how to trim it back; will work on that.  In the meanwhile to answer your question: msgs is a structure that holds various fields that need to be parsed from the log in addition to the actual log lines stored in char *dump.

Comment: Valgrind usually catches errors before many other tools, including gdb. Valgrind in this case caught you falling off the end of an array, which caused some corruption in the heap variables used to track allocations. Later, `realloc` or `free` found the corrupted allocation data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
msgs.msgs[rp->index].dump[len1] = '\0'; // add null terminator
```

after

```
realloc(msgs.msgs[rp->index].dump, sizeof(*tmp)*len1)
```

is an out-of-bounds write. The last valid index is `len1 - 1`.

---

With the code still aborting after that has been fixed, it might be that

```
// rp->line is malloc'ed then bzero'ed and strcpy'ed to contain the log line read from file
strcat(msgs.msgs[rp->index].dump, rp->line);
```

the `strcpy` to `rp->line` wrote outside the allocated buffer. The only other candidate I can see in the function is

```
msgs.msgs[rp->index].dump
```

If that is not 0-terminated, the `strlen` can run off the allocated buffer, and the `strcat` afterward can again write outside the allocated memory. The latter can be avoided by setting

```
msgs.msgs[rp->index].dump[len0] = 0;
```

after the realloc and before the `strcat`.

---

Setting `rp` to `NULL` after freeing

```
free(rp);
// prevent double free
rp = NULL;
```

is pointless, since `rp` is a local variable, and the function returns immediately after. The passed-in pointer `params` still holds the old address (strictly, its value becomes indeterminate, but in practice, the bits won't change) in the caller. That opens the possibility that the caller believes the pointer still points to valid memory.

Comment: Thanks for the catch!  `len1 = len0 + rp->len + 1` already add 1 for the NULL so I should have done `len1 - 1` for the null character.  I made that fix but valgrind still complains about the same issue.  I will see if I can find any other part of the code that may be causing this and post relevant info.

Comment: I've added a couple more possible causes, check them.

Comment: Thank you! `msgs.msgs[rp->index].dump[len0] = 0;` solved it.  I thought I was null terminating it but I guess that wasn't the case even after bzero and `msgs.msgs[rp->index].dump[len1-1] = '\0';`!?  Going to study the code a bit more to make sure I really understand the program flow.  Once again thank you!

Comment: You `bzero`ed it only when `len0 == 0`. However, if `msgs.msgs[rp->index].dump[len0] = 0;` has an effect, that means that `msgs.msgs[rp->index].dump` wasn't 0-terminated in the first place. You need to find where it is filled without a 0-terminator, and fix that.

Comment: Actually the program still crashed but a seg fault which I thought was unrelated to the current problem.  After more debuging with valgrind I noticed that even with my `malloc` and `bzero` combinations I still got use of uninitialized values, so I replaced all the `malloc()` and `bzero` combinations with `calloc` aand haven't hear a word from valgrind.  Still unsure why malloc and bzero was not sufficient, but as you mentioned something must be going over allocated space...going to read through entire code again.  Anyways, thanks for all the help!